# Route a request with specific format to a different controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a route which routes a request to `somepath/:id(.:format)` to `somecontroller#show`.

This goes for every request in any format. However, I have one condition where `somepath/:id.png` should return an image, and the code for that is already implemented in `othercontroller#show`.

I thought it would be best to route the .png requests to `othercontroller` instead of duplicating the code.

What would be the way to achieve this?
I've considered using constraints, but I am not sure if that would be the correct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way i see is to use

```
match 'somepath/:id.png' => 'othercontroller#show'
match 'somepath/:id(.format)' => 'somecontroller#show
```

This will route all .png requests to other controller, and all other to somecontroller.

Be **sure** that you place png route **before** the other.

Comment: This pretty much works, just had to add `:format => :png`. Only pitfall is that it doesn't enforce that format, so I can actually access `somepath/id.png.json`.